# lxml is not detecting empty div as expected

Tags: python, lxml

For the below input, `lxml` modifies the `div` as if it understands that `div` can't be inside `p`.

Can anyone tell me how to just get the `<div></div>` for this type of input? I want to correct the input HTML.

Do I need to switch to `BeautifulSoup`?

```
from lxml import etree

html_string = """
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <p align="center">
  <div></div>
  This line should be centered.
  </p>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>
         <div></div>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
"""

html_element = etree.fromstring(html_string)

page_break_elements = html_element.xpath("//div")

(Pdb) etree.tostring(html_element[1][0][0])
b'<div/>\n  This line should be centered.\n  '
```

I just want the below element to move it around.

```
<div></div>
```

For anyone curious, these are page-break `div`s used for PDF generation `<div style="page-break-after:always"></div>` that specify page-breaks. I get input from TinyMCE which doesn't position it correctly so I am trying to move it to the `body` element.

Output Desired

```
from lxml import etree

html_string = """
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div></div>
  <p align="center">
  This line should be centered.
  </p>
  <div></div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

Comment: I used BeautifulSoup and wrote a code to achieve my goal http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/136402/correcting-a-div-used-for-page-break-inside-p-by-moving-to-the-body-element

Comment: Can you add a few more divs and what you expect as output?

Comment: Yeah any such div should be moved to body level. That is my desired output. My code review solution seems to but I have to test the lxml solution.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I added more div's and the desired output. My code review code works fine. I wanted to do this with lxml if possible and not using BeautifulSoup.

Comment: so you want to move each div to precede the furthest  ancestor back before the  body?

Comment: Yeah @PadraicCunningham. Since these are used for page-break that is where I think it belongs.

Comment: My code review example achieves this using BeautifulSoup. Just couldn't make it work with lxml because of this issue. Apparently it is the tail as mentioned by @mljli

Comment: but you have it working now yes?

Comment: yes it is fine now @PadraicCunningham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [soupparser](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) in *lxml* and still process the data with xpaths etc..:

```
from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring

html_element = fromstring(html_string)
```

That will maintain `<div></div>` inside the p.

Comment: @Padriac, Is there a reason why this works like this in lxml? Why this difference?

Comment: @Nishant, libxml2 tries to  give you properly structured html, using soupparser is a lot more lenient. If you look at the meta/head example on the docs it is pretty much the same idea your own issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass some additional arguments to change the behavior of tostring():

```
etree.tostring(d, method="html", with_tail=False)
'<div></div>'
```

Comment: My problem is not the `tostring`, I wanted page_break_elements to be independent so that I can transfer it elsewhere. I created a solution using BeautifulSoup in any case anyone can review.

Comment: Yeah, lxml has its limitations. The way it checks for syntax does not works well with elaborated HTML documents.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote on this but that this is a tail is a key input for me to work upon. https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text. So this is a good answer.